# Rubbermaid garden cart tires

Tags: repair

I know you've seen these things. It's an indestructible black fiber-plastic cart body and a pair of 20 x 2.125 inch wheels with plastic spokes.

[image: Cart photo]

Does anyone know if I can replace the tires with the same size bicycle tires with tubes on the original wheels? Hate to throw out the wheels which also are shaping up to be indestructible (but not the tires).

Comment: most likely yes; it has an inner tube and all that, just like a bike tire. take it into a reputable bike shop and they can get you set up on the spot or at least order you one.

Comment: Rubbermaid sells the entire unit (wheel, tire, tube) as a replacement part (Tractor Supply stocks it/others might).  If you only need an innertube I'm sure you can pick that up in the bike parts at Walmart

Comment: Yeah, see that's the problem. They don't sell a replacement tire and the entire thing is about $100 and I need 2. A new cart costs $200. There are aftermarket wheels with tires about $40 each, but if I could do the bicycle tire/tube option it would be about $12 each.

Comment: Tractor Supply Company sells the [entire wheel part](https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/rubbermaid-replacement-20-in-semi-pneumatic-wheel-for-75-cu-ft-big-wheel-cart?cm_vc=-10005) for $40.  Walmart sells a [20" inner tube](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Bell-Sports-Cycle-Products-1006520-20-Regular-Bicycle-Inner-Tubes/17619560) for $3.77

Comment: Excellent question. I have the same cart and despise the squishy foam tires. Some of the commenters above seem to be unaware that they're not pneumatic on the newer generation.

Comment: @isherwood you're correct, I have the pneumatic tire version, and didn't know there was another version.  And I've used the Walmart inner tub in it when someone else popped the tire while inflating.

Comment: @isherwood: you can see the valve stems in the OP's photo, why would foam need that?

Comment: That's a stock photo, and OP may not have been aware of the pneumatic version. The question seems to imply tubeless tires.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 of these on my farm, we used mountain bike tires on the one that broke. We thought the wider and heavier rims would be needed even though we only carry sawdust for bedding stalls I think they have been on for 3-4 years and we did change the tubes that came with the rim & tire to the thorn resistant after a couple of flats.